# HighChart Pie Chart click on legend item to trigger drilldown

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am having trouble trying to trigger the drilldown event from legend item click event handler. In the example the drilldown is triggered when clicking on a pie slice but clicking on a legend item will show/hide the slice.

I'm trying to asynchronously load the data for an item.

An example of the [drilldown handler](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwd2uj56/):

```
  drilldown: function(e) {
      console.log(".....", "on drilldown item", e, this);
      var chart = this
      , serieData = [];
      if (!e.seriesOptions) {
        chart.showLoading('Loading ...');
        setTimeout(function() {
          chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, {
            name: 'Some sub item',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
              name: 'bla',
              y: 56.33
            }, {
              name: 'da da',
              y: 24.03,
              drilldown: true
            }, {
              name: 'ba ba ba',
              y: 10.38,
              drilldown: true
            }]
          });
          chart.hideLoading();
        }
        , 10);
      }
    }
  }
```

And the legend item handler:

```
  point: {
      events: {
        legendItemClick: function(e) {
          console.log(".....", "clicked legend item", e, this);
          //in drilldown chart = this but how can I get it here?
          //in drilldown e has seriesOptions, not this e
          //in drilldown e has point, not this e
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can trigger the drilldown from legendItemClick by calling target's Highcharts click event.

```
pie: {
    showInLegend: true,
    point: {
      events: {
        legendItemClick: function(e) {
          if (e.target.drilldown != undefined) {
            e.target.hcEvents.click[0]();         
          } else {
            return false;
          }    
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ueetz0b6/8/

You have to check to see if the target has drilldown, or the call will fail. If you don't call the click event, you then need to return false, or it will trigger the default legend click behavior.

**EDIT:** This was tested in Highcharts 4.2.3. It may not work in older versions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this must be a recent adition as I am unable to make it work with 4.1.7 and was unable to find hcEvents in the Highcharts API documentation (or what the event object is that is passed to the handler). http://jsfiddle.net/ueetz0b6/9/ I'll mark it is right answer if youd be so kind as to add a version warning.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about that. Edited to note the version I am using.

Answer (score 3):

***From version 4.2.0 (Highcharts.version) you can use friggle's answer***

Not sure what e.seriesOptions is supposed to be or where it is but will try to figure it out when I have more time.

I used the [following](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwd2uj56/10/):

```
pie: {
    showInLegend: true,
    point: {
      events: {
        legendItemClick: function(e) {
          console.log(".....", "clicked legend item", e, this);
          //in drilldown chart = this but how can I get it here:
          var chart = $('#container').highcharts();//<=calling without parameters
                                                   //causes it to return the chart
          //in drilldown e has seriesOptions, not this e (ignoring now)
          //in drilldown e has point, not this e
          drilldownHandler.call(chart,{point:e.target});
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```