# addSeriesAsDrilldown is not a function

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I used the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33951077/1641941) solution to get highcharts to drill down when a legend item is clicked.

The problem is that sometimes addSeriesAsDrilldown is undefined. I am currently trying to reproduce on fiddle but am unable.

`$("#piechart").highcharts().addSeriesAsDrilldown` would give me an object that does not have addSeriesAsDrilldown

Yet in some pages I will get an object that has addSeries but not addSeriesAsDrilldown for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Page was missing the script `HighCharts/modules/drilldown.js`

After having 2 fiddles (one from the default example and one from the drilldown example):

http://jsfiddle.net/tqdpcpr2/
and
http://jsfiddle.net/wL39dn2d/

Changed them to have the same code I noticed one adds drilldown.js